# This requires dotnet cli to be on the path. Make sure to install .NET Core SDK 2.0 https://www.microsoft.com/net/core eclipse azure functions error

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions

I am getting the above message when trying to run azure function sample([Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-java-maven))

I am getting this error when trying to run from eclispe. Dotnet cli is working from command prompt. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: How is it related to Java?

Comment: and did you make sure it is installed and on the path ans the error message says?

Comment: Yes it is installed on the path i.e. C:\Program Files\dotnet and it is present on the path enviornment variable

Comment: @VPK There is a documentation for creating azure functions with java/maven. I have given the link in the post.

Comment: @AJN The doc let us run the java azure function in command window. Did you try to run it in command window.

Comment: I tried to run the azure function using command window, but it still gave the same message as previous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Followed this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local) , you need to install [.NET Core 2.0](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/windows?utm_expid=.-Fmi9Q05Ry2oXQgdtPElHw.0&utm_referrer=).

Then you need to install Azure Functions Core Tools 2.X via the command:

```
npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools@core
```

[image]

Hope it helps you.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Jay Gong, but I followed the similar steps to run the azure functions using java/maven. But when I was reading the document link posted by you, I tried to run the command's func,azfun and azurefunctions which gave the same message as stated in the post. Maybe this gives a hint, don't know.

Comment: Can you please check if these command's are working on your cmd prompt please.

Comment: @AJN Hi,AJN. Yes yes, it works well on my side. I run the command: func init TestForCreate  and the project were inited successfully. Please see my add screenshot.

Comment: but I am getting the same message when I run the fucn command. Thanks

Comment: @AJN Would you please post your command prompt screenshot ? Let me check the complete error and I'll try to help you solve the issue. Thx.

Comment: I have added the screen shot please check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164311/discussion-between-jay-gong-and-ajn).

Comment: Thank you @Jay Gong, I had to install the .net framework. But it gave this message when I installed azure-functions-core-tools 1.X. Thank you very much

Comment: When I tried to run the func command after installing azure-functions-core-tools 1.X it gave a pop-up saying to install .net framwork.